# Aurelia Value Converter Buggy Behavior with percentage

Tags: aurelia, numeral.js

I am trying to convert a user input to a percentage using `aurelia converter` and `Numeral.js`.

Here is the gist: https://gist.run/?id=5bbfa902b1d14bff6f506dfcf2045370

The conversion is buggy. Basically, when I am entering the number, it does not behave as expected. Sometimes, I am not able to enter the value, and sometimes it just enters wrong value. The behavior is random.

I am not sure if the error is caused by `value converter` trying to convert the number at the same time I am typing. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's trying to update on every key stroke. You want it to update after leaving the input. Try using `value.bind="score | numberFormat & updateTrigger:'blur'"` instead.

You can learn more about binding behaviors in the [Aurelia docs](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/binding/latest/binding-binding-behaviors).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.